# Altering viewController variable from adapter?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UILabel` variable in my viewController: `class AwardsViewController: UICollectionViewController`. The viewController's collectionView has an adapter that has all the necessary collection view functions which gets connected like this:

```
@IBOutlet var awardsCollectionView: UICollectionView!  // The collection view
private var adapter = AwardsCollectionAdapter()        // The adapter
awardsCollectionView.dataSource = adapter
awardsCollectionView.delegate = adapter
```

I want to change the `UILabel` inside the view controller when the user clicks on one of the collection view cells, i.e. in this function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
   // ...change text of viewController's label
}
```

Does anyone know how I might get access to the variable inside the view controller from within this function in the adapter? The label is programatically added so it's not in the storyboard, it's just scoped to the viewController class.

```
class AwardsViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found out how to do it by myself. I make a `label : UILabel!` variable in the adapter, then in the `viewDidLoad` of the controller I set the `adapter.label` to `self.label`. From then I can manipulate that label within the adapter's functions.

That was much more difficult than I thought it'd be, yet simple now that I see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways how to do it and, personally, the one you chose is the worst one. You're coupling the adapter with the view controller: in the next future they cannot live separately and you can't reuse the code.
Abstracting the data communication by passing only the string, or better, the whole model that represent that row will be more reusable.

You can decide whether to use `NotificationCenter`, `Delegate pattern`, `closures` and others.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'm pretty new to this so learning this is really helpful.